# Bind IsEnabled of button to IsChecked of toggle button UWP

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm trying to bind the enabled property of a button to the checked property of another button in UWP.

```
    <CommandBar DefaultLabelPosition="Right" VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
            <AppBarButton Icon="Add" Label="Add Images" Command="{x:Bind ViewModel.AddImagesCommand}"/>
            <AppBarSeparator/>
            <AppBarToggleButton x:Name="buttonSelect" Label="Select"/>
            <AppBarButton Icon="SelectAll" Label="SelectAll" Click="{x:Bind gridViewInputImages.SelectAll}" IsEnabled="{x:Bind buttonSelect.IsChecked}"/>
        </CommandBar>
```

However, I get the error Invalid binding assignment : Cannot directly bind type 'System.Nullable(System.Boolean)' to 'System.Boolean'. Use a cast, converter or function binding to change the type

I guess I could fix this by binding to an intermediate value in the ViewModel, but is there a way to do this in XAML?

Answer (score 3):

Use it in XAML like this:

```
<CommandBar
            DefaultLabelPosition="Right"
            VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
            <AppBarButton
                Icon="Add"
                Label="Add Images"
                Command="{x:Bind ViewModel.AddImagesCommand}" />
            <AppBarSeparator />
            <AppBarToggleButton
                x:Name="buttonSelect"
                Label="Select" />
            <AppBarButton
                Icon="SelectAll"
                Label="SelectAll"
                Click="{x:Bind gridViewInputImages.SelectAll}"
                IsEnabled="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=buttonSelect, Converter={StaticResource NullBoolConverter}}" />
        </CommandBar>
```

With the converter like this:

```
public class NullBoolConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return false;

        return (bool)value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Declare your converter in your page StaticResources:

```
<converters:NullBoolConverter
        x:Key="NullBoolConverter"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not bind the nullable value to bool for bool is not null.

The IsEnabled value is `bool` and the IsChecked value is `bool?`. You should write a convert to convert `bool?` to bool.